# Device Name for iPad Mini Retina

Tags: ios, ipad, uname

on IOS calling uname() will return the device name. The only doc i could find is [this](http://gfxbench.com/device.jsp?benchmark=gfx27&D=Apple%20iPad%20Air&testgroup=system) website but it does not contain the iPad Mini Retina in the list.

Does anyone know what uname() will return on that device ?

Thanks,

Razvan.

Comment: i guess this question can be ignored :)) ... i only found out now that the device has not been lunched yet. i will reply with an answer when i find this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [list](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models). Looks like it contains all Apple devices. According to this list iPad mini Retina WiFi is iPad4,4 and iPad mini Retina Cellular is  iPad4,5

Comment: Thanks for the list , this list is much better than the one i had.It seems that iPad Mini with retina is labeled iPad Mini 2G